# jQuery select option with button

Tags: jquery, html-select

Is it possible to select special `<option>` item with jQuery by pressing button?

For example :

```
<a id="item1" href="#">Item 1</a>
<a id="item2" href="#">Item 2</a>
<a id="item3" href="#">Item 3</a>

<form>
.......
<select id="items" name="items">
<option value="1">I dont know</option>
<option value="2">Item 1</option>
<option value="3">Item 2</option>
<option value="4">Item 3</option>
</select>
.........

</form>
```

If you press the second button than in form automatically selects second option. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple jQuery way  of doing it.

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var select_num = $(this).index() + 1;
    $('#items option').eq(select_num).attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

Here is the example [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/SEqZG/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (item 2 link selects item 2 in list):

```
$('#item2').click(function(){
  $('#items option:nth-child(3)').attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

And similar function for each button/link.

Comment: and so is this. any idea on how to make them so that it works dynamically?

Comment: Look at my post for how to do it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#item1').click( function() {
   $('#items option[value="2"]').attr('selected', true); 
});
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/RVUDa/

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your  tags in a block element with an id.  This will help make it more efficient when you have a lot of items to click on because it is only one listener instead of one listener for each item in the list.

```
<div id="buttons">
  <a id="item1" href="#">Item 1</a>
  <a id="item2" href="#">Item 2</a>
  <a id="item3" href="#">Item 3</a>
</div>
```

Then for your jQuery code, you could do this:

```
$('#buttons').click(function(e)
{
   var num = $(e.target).index() + 1;
   $('option:nth-child(' + num + ')', '#items').attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```